# How to get the url path of a view function in django

Tags: python, django

As an example:

view.py

```
def view1( request ):
    return HttpResponse( "just a test..." )
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url( r'^view1$', 'app1.view.view1'),
)
```

I want to get the URL path of `view1`. How can I do this.
I want to avoid hard coding any URL paths, such as "xxx/view1".

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls).

```
from django.urls import reverse

reverse('app1.view.view1')
```

If you want to find out URL and redirect to it, use [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)

```
from django.urls import redirect 

redirect('app1.view.view1')
```

If want to go further and not to hardcode your view names either, you can [name your URL patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) and use these names instead.

Answer (score 23):

This depends whether you want to get it, if you want to get the url in a view(python code) you can use the `reverse` function([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse)):

```
reverse('admin:app_list', kwargs={'app_label': 'auth'})
```

And if want to use it in a template then you can use the `url` tag ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#url)):

```
{% url 'path.to.some_view' v1 v2 %}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want the url of the view1 into the view1 the best is request.get_path()

Comment: This is actually not correct (thought it may have been in an earlier release). To get the path from the request object, you can either use `request.path` or `request.get_full_path()` as of django 1.11+

Answer (score 4):

As said by others, `reverse` function and `url` templatetags can (should) be used for this.

I would recommend to add a name to your url pattern

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url( r'^view1$', 'app1.view.view1', name='view1'),
)
```

and to reverse it thanks to this name

```
reverse('view1')
```

That would make your code easier to refactor

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course you can get the url path of view named 'view1' without hard-coding the url.

All you need to do is - just import the 'reverse' function from Django urlresolvers.

Just look at the below example code:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def some_redirect_fun(request):

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('view-name'))
```

Comment: Using reverse('url_name') as shown in DrTysa's answer is far easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse) function for this. You could specify namespaces and names for url-includes and urls respectively, to make refactoring easier.

Answer (score 1):

***Universal approach***

0. install [Django extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) and add it to INSTALLED_APPS
1. Generate a text file with all URLs with corresponding view functions

`./manage.py show_urls --format pretty-json --settings=<path-to-settings> > urls.txt`

like

`./manage.py show_urls --format pretty-json --settings=settings2.testing > urls.txt`

2. Look for your URL in the output file `urls.txt`

```
    {
        "url": "/v3/blockdocuments/<pk>/",
        "module": "api.views.ganeditor.BlockDocumentViewSet",
        "name": "block-documents-detail",
    },
```

Comment: @IceFire yep, sorry - first you need to install Django extensions app and add it to installed apps https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions [added to the answer]